# Struts file upload using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts

I have one legacy project where we are using Struts 1. I have one requirement to upload some PDF file and I want to do it using jQuery AJAX. Could you please let me know if there is any way?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you can send multipart/form-data through ajax. I remember resorting to form submission when I had to do a multiple selection file upload using struts 1.x in one of my projects, but I have seen a couple of threads which say so.
For your reference, please go through them and let me know if that helps.
[file upload using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax) and [File upload using jQuery ajax plugin](http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/ajax-style-file-upload-in-java-web-application-using-jquery/).

Do let me know if you are able to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks @Priyanshu. I tried with jquery form and it worked successfully.